# Docker build failed in SPA React with Asp Core Project

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, dockerfile

My Docker File

#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN apt-get install -y libpng-dev libjpeg-dev curl libxi6 build-essential libgl1-mesa-glx
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_lts.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs


FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN apt-get install -y libpng-dev libjpeg-dev curl libxi6 build-essential libgl1-mesa-glx
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_lts.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["LT-Service/LT-Service.csproj", "LT-Service/"]
COPY ["DAL/DAL.csproj", "DAL/"]
RUN dotnet restore "LT-Service/LT-Service.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/LT-Service"
RUN dotnet build "LT-Service.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "LT-Service.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "LT-Service.dll"]
```

error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2 were not found.

Answer (score 0):

Your app targets .NET framework which is Windows only, so you can't run it in a Linux container. Based on the images you use, you should target .NET 5.